# Is :hover:after supported in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I have a flyout menu where at the end of "Quick Links" I use the :after pseudo-element on the first LI tag to display an icon from a sprite file.

The HTML:

```
<ul class="rs-quick-links-nav">
   <li>
    <a href="#">QUICK LINKS</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Enhanced Recipe Search</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Recipe Collections &amp; Favorites</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Cooking Tips &amp; Techniques</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Shopping &amp; Storing</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Tools &amp; Products</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">New Uses for Old Things</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Guide to Ingredients</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
.rs-quick-links-nav { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 20px; }
.rs-quick-links-nav > li { float: left; position: relative; white-space: nowrap; height: 19px; padding: 4px 0 4px 0; }
.rs-quick-links-nav > li > a { color: #999999; display: block; font: normal 1.2em Arial, sans-serif; }
.rs-quick-links-nav > li:after { content: ' '; background: transparent url('@static.base@/i/rs-global-sprite.png') -220px 0 no-repeat; height: 19px; position: absolute; top: 0; right: -22px; width: 21px; }
.rs-quick-links-nav > li > a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
.rs-quick-links-nav > li:hover:after { content: ' '; background: transparent url('global-sprite.png') -220px -20px no-repeat; height: 19px; position: absolute; top: 0; right: -22px; width: 21px; }
.rs-quick-links-nav li ul { background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 4px solid #69b8b8; left: -9999px; padding: 2px 8px; position: absolute; top: 24px; visibility: hidden; z-index: 9900; }
.rs-quick-links-nav li:hover ul { left: auto; right: -18px; visibility: visible; }
.rs-quick-links-nav li li { padding: 2px 0; }
.rs-quick-links-nav li li + li { border-top: 1px dotted #333333; }
.rs-quick-links-nav li li a { color: #666666; display: block; font: normal 1.2em/30px Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; height: 30px; padding: 0px 8px; }
.rs-quick-links-nav li li a:hover { background: #f6f6f6; }
```

What is supposed to happen is that when you hover over the LI tag, I change the icon to an active color.

.rs-quick-links-nav > li:hover:after seems to work in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, but not IE8 (I don't care about anything before IE8).  According to QuirksMode, IE8 supposedly supports :hover and :after, so I'm not sure why .rs-quick-links-nav > li:hover:after does not work.  Does anybody have any ideas how to make this work (even if I have to do something in Javascript).

EDIT: DOCTYPE is the HTML5 doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

EDIT: JSFiddle fragment here
http://jsfiddle.net/tangst/hA7FH/

Comment: According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=after), *"IE8 is not able to combine :after with other hierarchical elements"*. Perhaps what they meant to say is IE8 is not able to combine *pseudoselectors*. I could be wrong though, haven't tested it.

Comment: @Christian Varga: That note seems dubious - it states "For example .myClass:last-child:after will work in Firefox, Chrome or Safari, but not in IE8." but that's because :last-child doesn't work in IE8, period. It has nothing to do with :after, or with combining pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. For the record, .myClass:first-child:after *does* work, and so should :hover:after usually.

Comment: it looks like no issues in IE8.. Because i tested a similar html test code im able to see the background image. Can you check whether some styles is getting overridden..

Comment: Well, IE8's developer tool isn't great, so I can't see pseudo-elements, but I don't see any conflicts, but I can' say for sure.

Comment: Can you set up a test case on http://jsfiddle.net? Make sure to provide the right image URLs in the test case so we can see them.

Comment: Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/tangst/hA7FH/2/  I resolved those @static.base@ references in the CSS to the actual sprite images.  IE8 still doesn't do what I want, so I think I can safely disclaim any concern about conflicting CSS styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to write some Javascript to control the hover event of that element and style the element that way.  It's not quite perfect in IE8, but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

in your `:after:hover` rule add `content:"";`. this will force a redraw

Comment: You can also add `content:" "` and `content:"   " /*two spaces*/` for more variation to make ie8 redraw on more selectors.

Answer (score 1):

What does your doctype look like?

IE8 does handle pseudo-selector but if you don't have a strict doctype the :hover selector will only work on anchors.

Comment: You mean to say "if you *don't* have a strict doctype". Also, without it the :after selector won't work at all either.

Comment: Doctype is the HTML5 type ("DOCTYPE HTML"), so I would think it triggers standards mode.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of great options:

- Use a shim.  This lets you retro-fit (due the cascading nature of css) and fix 'older browser lack of support' issues.  For example: http://selectivizr.com/
- Use jQuery 1.8.1+ which provides support for these kind of things for older browsers.

Comment: We're using jQuery 1.7.2 at work.  Is there something in 1.8.1+ that would help me with this matter?  I ended up attaching a .hover() listener on the li tag.

I will look into Selectivizr though.

Comment: Alas, selectivizr doesn't cover :after.